# Vue components - recursive rendering or what is the problem here?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a new Vue app with 2 components but the components don't render.
The error is - "Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."
I read quite a bit on the problem but could not identify the problems in the code unlike with others' codes.

Seems OK to me, not the first app with components I've written :/

App:

```
require('../../lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2/jquery.event.drag-2.2');
require('../../lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2/jquery.event.drag.live-2.2');
require('../../lib/jquery.event.drop-2.2/jquery.event.drop-2.2');
require('../../lib/jquery.event.drop-2.2/jquery.event.drop.live-2.2');

import Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;

import tournamentCourtManager from 
'../../components/tournament/courtManager/courtManager';
import tournamentScheduleButton from 
'../../components/tournament/tournamentScheduleButton';
import { store } from "../../store/store";

new Vue({
    el: '#tournamentMatchSettingsApp',
    store,
    components: { 'tournamentCourtManager' : tournamentCourtManager, 
'tournamentScheduleButton' : tournamentScheduleButton }
});
```

tournamentCourtManager:

```
<template>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
    dadada
</button>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'tournamentScheduleButton',
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    mounted: function mounted() {
    },
    methods: {

    }
}
</script>
```

courtManager:

```
<template>
<div id="tournamentCourtManager">
..
    </div>
</template>
```

courtManager JS:

```
export default {
name: 'tournamentCourtManager',
components: {
    'match-cell': matchCell
},
data() {
    return {

    };
},
.... 
}
```

And the code that prompts the error -

```
       <tournamentschedulebutton></tournamentschedulebutton>
            <tournamentcourtmanager></tournamentcourtmanager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have named the components like `'tournamentCourtManager'` in the `components` object, they must be named like `<tournament-court-manager>` in the template.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have never encountered this naming issue before.